# How do I shuffle a multidimensional list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, shuffle

I know how to shuffle a simple List in Python by using the shuffle function from the random library `shuffle(myList)`

But how do I shuffle a multidimensional list?

```
myList[][]
```

shuffle(myList) didn't work.

Comment: And by "didn't work" you mean ...?

Comment: do you want all dimensions shuffled independently?

Comment: @Victory Yes, I want all dimensions shuffled independtly

Comment: [Numpy.random.shuffle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) possibly in combination with reshape

Comment: Just loop over it and shuffle each in place? `for el in myList: shuffle(el)`...

Comment: **Do you mean only shuffling individual sublists, or a (flat) shuffle that moves items between sublists?** Some answers interpreted this as the former, some as the latter. Should we assume the sublists have uniform length, or do we have to handle the ragged case too? It seriously would help if you posted sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to shuffle the top level list, then you can `map` the `shuffle` function to the sub lists like this in Python 2

```
from random import shuffle 

foo = []
foo.append([1, 2, 3])
foo.append([4, 5, 6])
foo.append([7, 8, 9])

shuffle(foo)
map(shuffle, foo)

print foo
```

[See python 2 fiddle](http://ideone.com/ByXAKs)

And like this in python 3

```
from random import shuffle 

foo = []
foo.append([1, 2, 3])
foo.append([4, 5, 6])
foo.append([7, 8, 9])

shuffle(foo)
for ii, sublist in enumerate(foo): 
    shuffle(foo[ii])

print(foo)
```

[see python 3 fiddle](http://ideone.com/KfuPZ0)

Comment: @Marcin It will work in Python 3 with `for u in foo: shuffle(u)` instead of the `map`.

Comment: It's not real shuffling, as each line will always be aligned (for instance [1,3,2].). You'll never have [1,2,5].

Comment: @Conchylicultor Depending on the use case this might be the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using only standard packages, the most efficient way I can think of is to unravel the array into a single list, shuffle, then reshape into a list of lists again.

```
import random

def shuffle2d(arr2d, rand=random):
    """Shuffes entries of 2-d array arr2d, preserving shape."""
    reshape = []
    data = []
    iend = 0
    for row in arr2d:
        data.extend(row)
        istart, iend = iend, iend+len(row)
        reshape.append((istart, iend))
    rand.shuffle(data)
    return [data[istart:iend] for (istart,iend) in reshape]

def show(arr2d):
    """Shows rows of matrix (of strings) as space-separated rows."""
    print ("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in arr2d))

# Generate some ragged data (5 rows):

arr2d = []
for i,a in enumerate("ABCDE"):
    n = random.randint(3,7)
    arr2d.append([a+str(j) for j in range(1,n+1)])

# display original and shuffled data

print ("Original...")
show(arr2d)
print ("Shuffled...")
show(shuffle2d(arr2d))
print ("Again...")
show(shuffle2d(arr2d))
```

Sample output (Python 2.7):

```
Original...
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
C1 C2 C3
D1 D2 D3
E1 E2 E3 E4 E5
Shuffled...
A3 C1 E5
C3 D3 A2 E1 D1
A1 E2 C2
B5 B4 B2
B1 D2 E4 E3 B3
Again...
B2 C2 C3
B1 D2 E5 A3 D1
A1 E3 A2
B5 D3 C1
B4 E4 E1 B3 E2
```

The above works equally well on Python 3.4, by the way.  The only version-dependent code features are print and range, and they are used agnostically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with trying to randomise questions and answers while maintaining the parring within the 2D list. At the time of writing this post, I have been learning python for only 3 weeks. My noob-solution was to create a random number, then use this number to pick from the list:

```
a_list = [["a4", 4], ["a3", 3],["a2", 2], ["a1", 1]]
a_pick = random.randint(0,3)
a_score = (a_list[a_pick])
```

This method allowed me to get a random selection from my list while keep the pairings I had written

Answer (score 0):

First, import the `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np
```

`numpy` has a method called called `random.shuffle()`. This method allwos you to shuffle a multi-dimensional list.

To shuffle a list using this method, you need to convert a list to a `ndarray` class, then pass it to `random.shuffle()`.

```
>>> foo = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> foo = np.array(foo)
>>> foo
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Now, shuffle it.

```
foo = np.random.shuffle(foo)
```

The value of `foo` will be something like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```